# Performance Issue with writing data to snowflake using spark df

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to read data from AWS RDS system and write to Snowflake using SPARK. 
My SPARK job makes a JDBC connection to RDS and pulls the data into a dataframe and on other hand same dataframe I write to snowflake using snowflake connector.

**Problem Statement :** When I am trying to write the data, even 30 GB data is taking long time to write.

**Solution I tried** :
1) repartition the dataframe before writing.
2) caching the dataframe.
3) taking a count of df before writing to reduce scan time at write.

Comment: Did you analyze if the slowness comes from reading via JDBC, or from writing to Snowflake? 30GB is not a lot of data for the Snowflake connector. But JDBC is famously inefficient for transferring large volumes of data.

Comment: Hard to answer without that info. But again, I strongly suspect the JDBC being the problem, not Snowflake or the connector.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  
I checked the stats and the issue is same you guys mentioned. Reading the data through JDBC connection is the bottle-neck.  

** Way around ** : I have partitioned the data on index and now loading using a loop. That way same data set is getting loaded pretty quickly.  
Any better way-around for the same ??

Comment: I wouldn't know, unfortunately, that's really a question to the RDS / Spark community.

Comment: Have you tried writing the dataframe out to an S3 location and using Snowflake's COPY statement to push it into the table?

Comment: That is one of the option but what I realized is that its problem with JDBC connection. Writing to S3/snowflake is taking same time while collecting all the data from dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

It may have been a while since this question was asked. If you are preparing the dataframe, or using another tool for preparing your data to move to Snowflake, the python connector integrates very nicely. 
Some recommendations in general for troubleshooting the query, including the comments that were recommended above, which are great, were you able to resolve the jdbc connection with the recent updates?

Some other troubleshooting to consider:

- Saving time and going directly from Spark to Snowflake with the Spark connector https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/spark-connector.html \
- For larger data sets, in general increasing the warehouse size for the session you are using, and looping in data in smaller 10 mb to 100 mb size files will increase compute speed.

Let me know what you think, I would love to hear how you solved it.

Comment: Hi,Running into a similar scenario in Azure Databricks. Wondering whether Azure Databricks can be used instead of Spark Connector to load data into SnowFlake? Is there any recommendation or best practices around this? Could anyone please share? Thanks in advance!